# How to statically link readline when using mingw on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, static-libraries, readline, static-linking

I made a small CLI tool that uses `readline()` for completion and powerful editing capabilities. On Linux, I can use the dynamic library easily by including it as a dependency in the package manager. On Windows, I would rather have it statically linked to keep my tool portable and not worry if readline dll is installed or not.

The question: I build the Windows version on Fedora Linux using mingw cross compiler, but I could't get static linking to work, how can I pull this off?

I tried linking to `libreadline.a`, and I got:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ./*.c -Wall -l:libreadline.a <other options>

<lots of errors like this>
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libreadline.a(terminal.o):(.text+0x7a3): undefined reference to `tputs'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libreadline.a(terminal.o):(.text+0x1063): more undefined references to `tputs' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libreadline.a(shell.o):(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `__chk_fail'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-dirent.o):(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: If you make an installer for your Windows application, include the readline DLL as well, and place it in the same directory as the executable program? That's basically what most Windows applications and installers do.

Comment: There is no installer, the tool has basically no dependencies other than readline, so static linking won't make it much larger (is is already about 200KB binary).

Comment: Then how about linking explicitly with the static library file?

Comment: I updated the question to show the errors while trying to statically link.

Comment: Unlike dynamic libraries, a static library is really nothing more than an archive of object files. Linking with a static library is like linking with the object files themselves. Therefore all dependencies of a static libraries are needed to be linked with as well.

Comment: `tputs` appears to come from ncurses, however there is no static ncurses for mingw in the Fedora repos... 
I will try to manually build the necessary ncurses library and get this thing to work, otherwise I guess the Windows version will not have readline, as it isn't a hard dependency.